# Node.js Installation error. Duplicates all of the environment variables (PATHS)

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, windows-10, npm-install

I am just trying to download node.js 64 bit version for windows 10 and some npms but every time I try to install node.js it duplicates all of the environment variables in PATH. This then clogs up all of the space and node.js fails to install correctly.

Please help. It's very frustrating.

I have tried removing all of the duplicate paths and reinstalling but it does the same thing every time. I have also tried googling it but haven't found the same problem online or a straight forward solution.